# Elasticsearch plugin ThreadPermission security exception

Tags: java, security, elasticsearch, plugins

I encountered the exception in elasticsearch plugin:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("org.elasticsearch.ThreadPermission"
>   "org.elasticsearch.ThreadPermission")     at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)

i tried the security policy:

> grant {
>       permission org.elasticsearch.ThreadPermission "*";
>    }

and even the following:

> grant {    permission java.security.AllPermission;  }

However,the exception still exists.

How to solve? thanks!

Comment: Without any further knowledge of this problem (or of elasticsearch), it'd be helpful to have more of the exception trace and perhaps more of the `java.security` debug trace (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars003.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try to append '-Djava.security.policy=/full/path/policy/file' in config/jvm.options
And restart.